# "pragma omp parallel for" in function not effective when function is called within another parallel loop

Tags: c++, multithreading, nested, openmp

Inside a parallelized 'for' loop I'm calling a function, which in turn contains an expensive calculation that I would like to parallelize with the remaining CPUs. However, my inner 'parallel for' directive is simply ignored.

This is for an image processing pipeline. The camera has 4 detectors and takes e.g. 100 images. I want to calculate for each detector the median of the 100 input images. Hence my outer loop uses 4 threads for the 4 detectors, and I want to use the remaining CPUs to parallelize the median calculation in the inner loop.

```
int main()
{
  // OUTER LOOP over various detectors
  # pragma omp parallel for
  for (int det=0; det<4; ++det) {
      // some serial work
      calculate_median(det);
  }
}

void calculate_median(int det)
{
   // some serial work

   #pragma omp parallel for num_threads(available_additional_threads)
   for (int pixel =0; pixel < numpixels; ++pixel) {
        // create a stack of pixels from the 100 input images
        // calculate median of stack
   }

   // more serial work
}
```

I calculate the the additional available threads based on how many detectors the camera has and on the number of CPUs on the user's machine. Like this there are never more threads running than there are CPUs.

What I observe is that the inner 'omp parallel for' is ignored, i.e. no matter the value of 'available_additional_threads', I get only a single thread.
HOWEVER, if I do set the outer loop to just a single thread, then the inner parallelization works as expected. This really puzzles me.
Thank you very much for any additional insight!

UPDATE / SOLUTION:
Setting 'omp_set_nested(true)' enabled the inner loop parallelization.

Comment: Investigate `omp_set_nested`. By default (without nested parallelism) the behavior you describe is exactly how OMP is specified to work.

Comment: Dear Max, that was it!  Setting  omp_set_nested(true)  solved my issue. Now I'm getting a segfault on one of my inner variables which I don't understand (yet). But the main question I have asked is answered/. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

You can use the collapse clause the compiler supports OpenMP 3.0

```
#pragma omp parallel for collapse(2)
for (int x = 0; x < x_max; ++x) {
    for (int y = 0; y < y_max; ++y) { 
    //parallelize this code here
    }
//IMPORTANT: no code in here
}
```

,but this seams to be not applicable here, since you have to do some serial work.

My experience is, that nested loops have a worse performance than one parallel loop, which is nicely panellized.

Usually, it is a good idea to just parallelize the outer loop. Since your outer loop only has 4 iterations, I think it is reasonable to use OMP just for the inner loop. The scheduler can handle load imbalances her better.

Keep in mind the golden rule of performace refactorings: Measure.

I suggest, that you use a tool such as Intel's Vtune Ampifier to measure how your performance is and if a nested loop would really help you.

Comment: Dear schorsch312, as you noted the 'collapse' clause is of no help for my problem. Also, the camera setups vary widely. Some of them have up to 72 detectors, i.e. many more than CPUs, and therefor for my inner loop I never request more than one thread. The system is fully loaded. What I wanted to optimize are the cases where I have more CPUs than detectors. The inner calculation is very expensive and parallelization overhead is no concern.

Comment: @MischaSchirmer, but `numpixels` should always be way larger than the number of cpus, right? If this is true, you have all processors occupied even if you parallize only the inner loop.

Comment: That's why I have the num_threads() clause there, limiting the number of CPUs to what is actually available for the inner loop.

Comment: Rather than trying to use nested parallelism, use taskloop which gives you load balancing and shares work from all levels of the hierarchy across the threads.